# How to send simple data from javascript to java application

Tags: java, javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a simple message from javascript. I want to receive the data in a java program (server), but I can't seem to figure out how to obtain the message in java.

Here is my javascript:

```
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("POST", ip, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("posX=" + posX + "&posX = " + posX);
```

I have 2 questions regarding this.

- Is the above the fastest method to send simple string data from
  javascript to a java program or can you recommend an alternative
  solution?
- How can I receive the above POST request from the javascript with java?

I really hope someone can help me out.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using a Java server to host the webpage that the javascript is running in?

Comment: treat it exactly the same way as if it was a form being submitted. There are lots and lots of tutorials on how to use ajax

Comment: Thank your for your answers. I am not using java server. It is a javascript in Telerik Kendo UI. I managed to send a POST request to the java server, by doing as Jiří Kantor suggeested. However, I can't seem to extract the parameters sent with the POST request. So if any of you know how to do this, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: JavaScript functions TO **save a JSON file** that can be read by java will do any good ? (basic javascript file saving)[http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/]

Answer (score 1):

As I've never done something like this, I don't know if there is any fastest method, but this way the Java application has to listen on TCP port 80 and that should be it. It should also send a HTTP response.

EDIT:
I have come up with two things after diving into the problem:

1. The POST data part is not terminated by newline, so if you use `BufferedReader` and its `readLine` method, it just hangs there and waits. It doesn't get terminated because #2
2. The AJAX request doesn't, apparently, close the socket, so the stream from which the java program reads is not terminated so you cannot end the reading by waiting for `read` method of `InputStreamReader` to return -1. The only way I found just this quickly was checking if the input stream is ready or not. 
   So a VERY CRUDE but minimal example would be:

   ```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;


   class TCPServer {

        public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
           ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(80);

           while(true) {
               Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
               InputStreamReader inFromClient = new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
               int c = 0;

               while(true) {
                   c = inFromClient.read();
                   System.out.print((char)c);
                   if(!inFromClient.ready()) {
                       break;
                   }
               }
               System.out.println("-------------------------");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This was what I was looking for! By listening on TCP, I received the POST request. But I can't seem to get the parameters, that I am sending with the request. Do you know how to extract these? Thanks you for your answer by the way!

Comment: Sorry for the messed up formatting, but I cannot get it to work :D

Answer (score 0):

I think HttpServer is what you are looking for.
It listens on port 80 to accept Http-Requests

[HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html)